# Pourriez vous identifier l'erreur ?

Tags: informatique

[image: Unresolved reference 'R']

Bonjour tout le monde,

S'il vous plaît, s'il y a quelqu'un qui a au moins une idée sur l'erreur générée par Android Studio ( version 3.1.2) ; Normalement j'ai essayé toutes les méthodes classiques (import android.R, import android.R.* , import com.namepackage.nameapp.R.layout.activity_main, clean-->builk, sync with gradle files...) mais en vain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern the French language so that it does not belong in french.stackechange.com

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que tu as mal compris l'idée de french.stackechange.com. Ce n'est pas la version française de stackoverflow.com, mais un site de question/réponse portant sur la langue française.

Je te conseille donc de supprimer cette question et de le poster sur son site correspondant.